# logrotate continues to rotate & compress already rotated logs

Tags: logrotate

I have a log that generates a new log file each day. Here is a listing of each log created since I turned on logging:

```
2019-01-04
2019-01-05
2019-01-06
2019-01-07
2019-01-08
```

This is the logrotate configuration. I have tried several iterations none of which result in the log being compressed and then "left alone" until it rolls off (hopefully in 90 days).

```
/etc/logrotate.d/remote

/var/log/remote/*/*[!.]gz
/var/log/remote/*/*.[!g]z
/var/log/remote/*/*.g[!z]
/var/log/remote/*/*[!.][!g]z
/var/log/remote/*/*[!.]g[!z]
/var/log/remote/*/*.[!g][!z]
/var/log/remote/*/*[!.][!g][!z]
{
    rotate 90
    daily
    missingok
    compress
}
```

This is a listing of the folder showing what logrotate is doing.

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jan  8 06:25 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4.0K Jan  4 09:44 ../
-rw-r----- 1 root adm     0 Jan  8 06:25 2019-01-04
-rw-r----- 1 root adm    20 Jan  7 06:25 2019-01-04.1.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm    20 Jan  6 06:25 2019-01-04.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  5.2K Jan  4 23:57 2019-01-04.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm     0 Jan  8 06:25 2019-01-05
-rw-r----- 1 root adm    20 Jan  7 06:25 2019-01-05.1.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm    20 Jan  6 06:25 2019-01-05.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  7.4K Jan  5 23:58 2019-01-05.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm     0 Jan  8 06:25 2019-01-06
-rw-r----- 1 root adm    20 Jan  7 06:25 2019-01-06.1.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  8.0K Jan  6 23:56 2019-01-06.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm     0 Jan  8 06:25 2019-01-07
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  7.8K Jan  7 23:55 2019-01-07.1.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  101K Jan  8 13:16 2019-01-08
```

I want to manage the number of days of logs that are retained and while I'm at it, compress the old logs. This is what I want to end up with:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jan  8 06:25 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4.0K Jan  4 09:44 ../
-rw-r----- 1 root adm    20 Jan  7 06:25 2019-01-04.1.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm    20 Jan  7 06:25 2019-01-05.1.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm    20 Jan  7 06:25 2019-01-06.1.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  7.8K Jan  7 23:55 2019-01-07.1.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  101K Jan  8 13:16 2019-01-08
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to rotate log files that end with a digit in the specified directory, so the log matching becomes:

```
/var/log/remote/*/*[0-9]
```

A problem you're running into is that `logrotate` probably has the `create` option set as default, meaning that after a logfile is rotated (meaning it is renamed and maybe compressed), a new logfile with the original name is created. This can be prevented by using the `nocreate` option.

However, you biggest problem is that your logfiles don't have a fixed name. `logrotate` keeps X versions of logfiles that have the same name; as the name changes every day, `logrotate` keeps one version of each day, so nothing ever gets removed.

It might work if you could convince whatever is creating these logfiles to have some prefix like "log-" so that the names become "log-2019-01-09" etc. Now you can tell `logrotate` to use `dateext` and `dateformat -%Y-%m-%d`, and hopefully this will trick `logrotate` to assume the date part was created by `logrotate` itself. The config then becomes something like:

```
/var/log/remote/*/log {
    nocreate
    dateext
    dateformat -%Y-%m-%d
    delaycompress
}
```

However if I were you I would not try to force `logrotate` to handle these logfiles which don't behave like `logrotate` expects. I would roll my own log expiry script, something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
DAYS=90
TOPDIR=/var/log/remote
cd $TOPDIR
for i in *; do
    if ! [ -d $TOPDIR/$i ]; then
        continue
    fi
    cd $TOPDIR/$i
    find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '????-??-??' -mtime +1 -exec gzip {} \;
    find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '????-??-??.gz' -mtime +$DAYS -delete
done
```

Comment: Bingo-nocreate! Wondered about the changing file names. I'd plagiarized my setup ;-) Thought I'd done something wrong in applying it. Example contained the means to direct the syslog to unique directories for each source and to name the log files on a daily basis. It then have a section on setting up logrotate to manage those. I think the original example never really actually worked. So part of my problem was trying to debug a setup that never worked.

Thanks!

I think I'll got with your suggested script to purge old logs as that's the most straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

For me what you are asking is pretty normal. Let's assume you have three files `file1.log, file2.log and file3.log` inside a folder in `/var/log/remote/` and you want to rotate them daily and keep the last 10 compressed. You can do it as follows:

1. Create a file in `/etc/logrotate.d/myfiles`.
2. Paste the following content in it.

   > /var/log/remote/*.log
   >   {
   >   rotate 10
   >   daily
   >   sharedscripts
   >   missingok
   >   compress
   >   }
3. You can test it running `logrotate` in debugging mode.

   > logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.d/myfiles
4. If you actually want to execute it now.

   > logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/myfiles